# Passing arguments from Excel VBA to Python (using Anaconda3)

Tags: python, excel, vba

When I execute the batch file "testing.bat" with Excel VBA, it is expected the results of var_a and var_b be 123 and 456 respectively.

It appears that the values 123 and 456 are unable to be passed to var_a and var_b.

Excel VBA code:

```vb
Sub testing()
    Shell ("C:\Users\...\Desktop\...\testing.bat " & "123 456")
End Sub
```

Batch file code:

```
call C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat
cd "C:\Users\...\Desktop\..."
testing.py %*
```

Python code:

```
import sys
var_a = sys.argv[1]
var_b = sys.argv[2]
print(var_a, var_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

`...` means nothing on Windows NT, the Windows that we use.

In Novell networks, 30 years ago, `...` meant go up two directories.

The Windows Network File Redirector for Win 9x supported Novell syntax.

Windows NT didn't.

Windows NT only supports one `.` for current directory (so really doesn't do anything) or two dots `..` for parent directory.

Comment: I guess OP just wanted to hide the details (username) and replaced it with dots

Comment: Yes, I just want to hide the details of the path.